# Root element name does not match. Expected

Tags: android, kml, saxparser

I am parsing an KML file using Android simplified version of the SAX API in which there is no handler.  The issue is that my call to

`RootElement root = new RootElement("kml");`

is crashing giving me an error like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.sax.BadXmlException: Line 2: Root element name does not match. Expected: 'kml', Got: 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2:kml'
```

This is the beginning of the file being parsed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">  etc...
```

I am going by the book, but still it is causing the error. I have seen other post at stack overflow on this but they relate to SAXParserFactory where you can disable XML Schema validation. Unfortunately, in here I cannot.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to specify the KML namespace; e.g. RootElement root = new RootElement(`"http://opengis.net/kml/2.2"`, "kml")

Comment: @JasonM1 thanks that worked out. One silly question, since the URL is "harcdcoded", what happens if they change the namespace of the KML in the future. The app would crash again, right?

Comment: namespace needs to match what you're parsing otherwise get parse error again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to specify the KML namespace in your [RootElement](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/sax/RootElement.html) to match what's in the KML file otherwise will get a parse exception. Not specifying a namespace is technically a special namespace that has an empty URI.

```
final String KML_NAMESPACE = "http://opengis.net/kml/2.2";
RootElement root = new RootElement(KML_NAMESPACE, "kml");
// ...
XMLReader reader = ...;
reader.setContentHandler(root.getContentHandler());
reader.parse(...);
```